# Windows Azure HPC Scheduler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, scheduler, hpc

Is Windows Azure HPC Scheduler still an active part of latest Windows Azure? I couldn't find its .NET SDK APIs either on NuGet or on Microsoft Web platform 4.6. The sample codes for HPC scheduler on MSDN do not run in Visual Studio 2012 and throws error for missing reference to the library Microsoft.HPC.Scheduler?

Will appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this?

I am using latest Windows Azure SDK for .NET v2.2

Answer (score 1):

It is something that was (**and still is**) for a while in Preview!

And if you open the official info page for [Windows Azure HPC Scheduler here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh560247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will notice that the only supported Windows Azure SDK versions are 1.7 and 1.8! The Windows Azure HPC Scheduler will **not** work with any other Azure SDK versions!

Good news is that you can install Azure SDK 1.8 side-by-side with SDK 2.2. Get the 1.7 or 1.8 from [official download site here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/).

And do **not** use Azure HPC Scheduler with Azure SDK different than 1.7 or 1.8. And do not forget it is a preview feature.